# Need help fixing or suppressing this TypeScript error: TS2742

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components, tslint, prettier

I have this file in a react native project:

```
import styled, { withTheme } from 'styled-components';
import { BaseText } from '../BaseText';

export interface BodyProps {
  textAlign?: string;
  fontSize?: string;
}

export const Body = withTheme(styled(BaseText)<BodyProps>`
  text-align: ${props => (props.textAlign ? props.textAlign : 'center')};
  font-size: ${props => (props.fontSize ? props.fontSize : '16px')};
`);
```

I upgraded react native from 0.61.5 to 0.63.2 and started getting this lint error wherever `withTheme` is being used:

> TS2742: The inferred type of 'Body' cannot be named without a
> reference to 'react-native/node_modules/@types/react'. This is likely
> not portable. A type annotation is necessary.

**I tried** several things, but the error remains the same:

1. Following [this post](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/227), I added `import React from "react";`
2. Tried to disable tslint by adding `/* tslint:disable */` above the `Body` declaration
3. Tried to disable tslint by adding `// tslint:disable-next-line` above the `Body` declaration
4. Played with dependency versions. Currently I have `"@types/react": "^16.9.49"`.

Comment: You have duplicate types that's what it means. Look at the path, its a nested `node_modules` directory in `node_modules/react-native/` You have conflicting dependencies

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks, but there is no `@types` directory inside `node_modules/react-native/`

Comment: That's weird. Remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` or whatever the lockfile is for your package manger and reinstall all dependencies

Answer (score 7):

Alternately, check your `package-lock.json` and `yarn.lock` -- are there multiple `@types/react` versions listed there? Try changing your `package.json` to have the same `@types/react` version as what `react-native` lists as a dependency.

It could be that you have multiple versions of the `@types/react` React typings, and the components are getting confused about which one to import from.

Answer (score 1):

By "a reference", TypeScript means the specific project you're working on doesn't have a (regular/dev/peer/optional) dependency in its `package.json`. You might be relying on a neighboring package to declare the dependency, or have coincidentally installed globally on your computer.

To resolve this, add `@types/react` as a `devDependency` to your `package.json` and install with your package manager of choice. That will satisfy TypeScript because it'll guarantee your package *definitely* has a reference to the (React) types it needs -- not just coincidentally.

```
npm i @types/react --save-dev
yarn add @types/react -D
```

---

We should also note that "tslint" and `tslint:disable` refer to [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint), a now-deprecated tool which is **not** the same as TypeScript. TSLint is a separate library that adds extra static analysis ("linting") onto TypeScript code. Put another way, TSLint is to TypeScript as ESLint is to JavaScript.

The error you're seeing is a TypeScript error, not a TSLint one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already have that devDependency as mentioned in the last line of my question. Thank you for explaining why `tslist:disable` isn't working.

Comment: Are you sure it's installed (`npm i` / `yarn`)? :) Note the file path, `react-native/node_modules/@types/react` -- for some reason, TypeScript thinks your `@types/react` is from a sub-module, not your direct listed dependency.

Answer (score 1):

The `withTheme` function returns a value of a specific type. In your case, TypeScript fails to properly infer this type which is why you get error [**TS2742**](https://typescript.tv/errors/#TS2742).

You can fix the problem by adding an explicit **type annotation** to `const Body`. It will look somewhat like this (depending on your version of `styled-components`):

```
import styled, { withTheme, WithThemeFnInterface } from 'styled-components';

export const Body: WithThemeFnInterface<{}> = withTheme(styled(BaseText)<BodyProps>`...`
```